# Replace two Shiny-inputs with one Shiny-input of same size

Tags: r, shiny

I have developed below Shinyapp :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(                   
        column(width = 12, checkboxInput(inputId = "Chose", label = "Chose", value = TRUE, width = 170)),


        column(width = 12, fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths =  c(200, 200, 600), 
                    textInput(inputId = "Text1", label = "Text1", value = "30,000", width = 190),
                    sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", label = "Slider1", min = 1, max = 30, value = 10, step = 0.10, post = "%", width = 310)))
        )
))
server <- function(input, output) {

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, I would like to design my UI in such a way, when user uncheck `checkboxInput`, then `textInput` and `sliderInput` will vanish together, and another `sliderInput` (with some other ID) will pop-up in the combined place of my original `textInput` and `sliderInput`.

I have explored `uiOutput` which could do the same, however I found that the updation is really 1:1, whereas here my plan is to have 2:1.

Can somebody share a pointer if that is possible to achieve.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(     
    column(width = 12, checkboxInput(inputId = "Chose", label = "Chose", value = TRUE, width = 170)),
    column(width = 12, fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths =  c(200, 200, 600), 
                                            uiOutput("test1"),
                                            uiOutput("test2"))),
           column(width = 12, fluidRow(splitLayout(cellWidths =  c(400, 600), 
                                                   uiOutput("test3")))

  ))
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {


  output$test1 <- renderUI({
    if(input$Chose == TRUE){
      sliderInput(inputId = "Slider1", label = "Slider1", min = 1, max = 30, value = 10, step = 0.10, post = "%", width = 310)
    }
  })

  output$test2 <- renderUI({
    if(input$Chose == TRUE){
      textInput(inputId = "Text1", label = "Text1", value = "30,000", width = 190)
    }
  })


  output$test3 <- renderUI({
    if(input$Chose == FALSE){
      sliderInput(inputId = "Slider2", label = "Slider2", min = 100, max = 300, value = 100, step = 0.10, post = "%", width = 600)
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```